# BitmapFactory.decodeResource

Tags: android, android-drawable, bitmapfactory

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cf_default);
Log.d(LOGTAG, "BitmapFactory.decodeResource()"
    + "\n\tw: " + bm.getWidth() + "\th: " + bm.getHeight()
);
```

The result is `w: 32 h: 32`

When the image is a lot larger than this.

Why?

How to get the real width and height?

Comment: That is the real width and height. It is the width and height of the `Bitmap` created using `decodeResource()`. As to why those values differ from your expectations, perhaps you have different versions of that resource in different resource sets, and you are thinking about the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to convert drawable to `BitmapDrawable` from where it's height and width can be computed

```
BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cf_default); 
int imageHeight = bmpDrawable.getBitmap().getHeight(); 
int imageWidth = bmpDrawable.getBitmap().getWidth();
```